# undefined method `chomp' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby

Boa noite a todos.

Estou aprendendo Ruby e me deparei com esse erro no codigo que estou criando e nao consigo prosseguir ou encontrar o erro.
Alguem sabe me dizer onde está o erro? :(
Estou tentando mas por saber pouco de ruby ainda nao consigo entender porque o codigo nao interpretou.

```
def sequencia_numerica(array, posicao)
    if posicao == 1 
        puts 2
    elsif posicao == 2
        puts 3
    else puts 2 * array[posicao - 1] + 3 * array[posicao - 2]
    end
end
```

puts "Digite a quantidade de entradas: "
n = gets.chomp
array = Array.new

for i in n
    puts "Digite o valor #{i}"
    array.push(gets.chomp)
end

for j in array.length
    if array[j] <= 0 || array[j] < 40
        sequencia_numerica(array,j)
    end 
end

---

## Atualização

Luiz muito obrigado. Consegui concluir o código realizando alguns ajustes. Foi de grande ajuda os ensinamentos, como estou aprendendo estes detalhes foram essenciais para corrigir os erros.

```
def sequencia_numerica(array, posicao)
    if posicao == 0 
        array[posicao] = 2
        return 2
    elsif posicao == 1
        array[posicao] = 3
        return 3
    else return 2 * array[posicao - 1] +  3 * array[posicao - 2]
    end
end
```

puts "Digite a quantidade de entradas: "
n = gets.chomp.to_i
array = Array.new

n.times do |i|
    puts "Digite o valor #{i}"
    array.push(gets.chomp.to_i)
end

n.times do |i|
    if array[i] <= 0 || array[i] < 40
        puts sequencia_numerica(array,i)
    end 
end

Comment: O que seria o `gets` do comando `gets.chomp` ? Segundo a [documentação](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) o método `chomp` é um método da [classe String](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html).

Comment: gets lê uma string da entrada padrão (digitada pelo usuário) e retorna uma String.

Comment: Que bom que pude ajudar! Caso a resposta tenha sido satisfatória pode elegê-la como resposta para ajudar outros membros. Bons estudos.

Answer (score 1):

No seguinte trecho você pede que o usuário insira a quantidade de elemento, mas depois tenta iterar sobre uma `String (undefined method`each' for "1":String (NoMethodError))`, primeiro que você precisa converter essa string em inteiro, e depois que mesmo sendo inteiro para que haja iteração, esse objeto precisa ser um collection (`Array`,`Hash`, etc)

```
puts "Digite a quantidade de entradas: "
n = gets.chomp
array = Array.new

for i in n
    puts "Digite o valor #{i}"
    array.push(gets.chomp)
end
```

Uma pequena modificação pode resolver:

```
puts "Digite a quantidade de entradas: "
n = gets.chomp.to_i
array = Array.new

n.times do |i|
    puts "Digite o valor #{i}"
    array.push(gets.chomp)
end
```

O segundo trecho temos outro erro `(undefined method`each' for 2:Fixnum (NoMethodError) )` novamente você está tentando iterar sobre um objeto não iterável, no caso um Fixnum (numeral). Observando você cria um Array e ao invés de iterar sobre esse, você transforma ele em numero para iterar, utilizamos nesse caso o próprio Array e está resolvido.

```
for j in array
```

Após isso colidimos com outro erro:  `[]': no implicit conversion of String into Integer (TypeError)` Você está fazendo comparações de inteiro com String, pois o resultado de chomp é uma String e no trecho `array[j] <= 0 || array[j] < 40` você está fazendo comparação com números.

Para resolver isso voltamos no loop em que capturamos cada entrada do usuário e convertemos a entrada em inteiro.

```
n.times do |i|
    puts "Digite o valor #{i}"
    array.push(gets.chomp.to_i)
end
```

Assim seu código funciona:

> ```
> Digite a quantidade de entradas: 
> 2
> Digite o valor 0
> 1
> Digite o valor 1
> 1
> 2
> 2
> ```

Código final seria algo como:

```
def sequencia_numerica(array, posicao)
    if posicao == 1 
        puts 2
    elsif posicao == 2
        puts 3
    else puts 2 * array[posicao - 1] + 3 * array[posicao - 2]
    end
end 


puts "Digite a quantidade de entradas: "
n = gets.chomp.to_i
array = Array.new

n.times do |i|
    puts "Digite o valor #{i}"
    array.push(gets.chomp.to_i)
end    

for j in array
    if array[j] <= 0 || array[j] < 40
        sequencia_numerica(array,j)
    end 
end
```